# Use Scanner on csv, iterate every time method is called

Tags: java, csv, parsing, java.util.scanner

I am trying to parse a text document that has release notes and grab specific ones. To do that I have a csv with the desired release note keys. I want to scan the csv and use each key to find the matching section of the release note, and print the description that follows.

I would like to use the Scanner class for this to practice with it.

The csv looks like:

```
foobar-123,foobar-127,foobar-129
```

The release note text doc looks like:

```
foobar-123: ewkjhlq kghlhrekgh

foobar-124: lkjhfgrelgkj nberg

foobar-127: ljdfgl kjwneglkjn fdg

foobar-129: lguwlrkguj gwrlekgj werlktj
```

The issue I am running into is iterating through the csv. I seem to keep grabbing the first string in the csv. I am trying to figure out how to save my place in the csv, so every time the method is called, it goes to the next string.

I'm thinking I could create a variable that saves the last found string, and then use scanner to find that and then grab the next string. But that would require scanning through the csv each time I want to progress and which does not seem efficient. What would be the best way to iterate through the csv using the Scanner class?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReleaseNotesScan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Open csv file with issue keys
        Scanner getIssueKeys = null;
        try {
            getIssueKeys = new Scanner(new FileReader("resources/Issues.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Open release notes
        Scanner releaseNotes = null;
        try {
            releaseNotes = new Scanner(new FileReader("resources/Release notes text.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get issue key from csv
        String issueKey = Finders.issueKey(getIssueKeys);

        //The below three lines are just for testing if I am iterating through the csv
        System.out.println(issueKey);
        Finders.issueKey(getIssueKeys);
        System.out.println(issueKey);




        //Get issue key and description
        String description = Finders.sectionContent(releaseNotes, issueKey);
        System.out.println(issueKey + ": " + description);

        //Close csv
        getIssueKeys.close();

        //Close release notes
        releaseNotes.close();
    }

}
```

My Finders class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Finders {
    //parse csv
    public static String issueKey(Scanner findIssues) {
        findIssues.useDelimiter(",");
        String issue = findIssues.next();

        return issue;
    }

    public static String sectionContent(Scanner releaseNotes, String heading) {
        while (releaseNotes.hasNextLine()){
            String found = releaseNotes.findInLine(heading);
            if (found != null){
                releaseNotes.findInLine(": ");
                String grabIt = releaseNotes.nextLine();
                return grabIt;
            }
            releaseNotes.nextLine();
        }
        releaseNotes.close();
        return "Not found";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the release note doc is not too big, you can read the whole file first and store the info in a `HashMap` using `foobar-123`, `foobar-124` etc as keys. Searching would be very efficient.

Comment: Don't attempt to parse CSV yourself, there are at least two excellent libraries that take care of all the details and corner cases for you.  Look at OpenCSV for instance.  There is no point in reinventing the wheel, and the libraries have been thoroughly tested and debugged.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep grabbing the first string in the csv"? Your csv file is simple and the scanner should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code to demonstrate how the application can be structured. I made some assumptions that the input file "issues" as a string (instead of a file, for brevity). The issues are stored in an array and release notes in `HashMap` collection. The release notes are read from the file, tokenized (split with ":" as delimiter) as the issue and its release-note text. The issue is the key and the release-note is the value in the map.

Finally, iterate each issue and get the corresponding release-note from the map.

**Example Code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MatchIssues {
    private static String [] issues;
    private static Map<String,String> releseNotes = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String [] args)
            throws IOException {
        getIssues();
        getReleaseNotes();
        for(String issue : issues) {
            // Match release notes for the issue
            System.out.println(releseNotes.get(issue));
        }
    }
    private static void getIssues() {
        String s = "foobar-123,foobar-127,foobar-129"; // use string for demo
        issues = s.split(",");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(issues));
    }
    private static void getReleaseNotes()
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new FileReader("release_notes.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String [] tokens = line.split(":");
            releseNotes.put(tokens[0].trim(), tokens[1].trim());
        }
        System.out.println(releseNotes);
    }
}
```

**release_notes.txt**:

```
foobar-123: aa ewk jhlq kghlhrekgh aa
foobar-124: bb lkjh fgrelgkj nberg bb
foobar-127: yy ljdfgl kjw neglkjn fdg yy
foobar-129: zz lgu wlrkguj gw rlekgj werlktj zz
```